# The text printed out for the Question class is not the text that I expect

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

When I follow the tutorial for Django, I found a problem that when I run Question.objects.all(), it then only printed out the class name instead of the text that I had already set. May I ask what is the method that I could print the text out instead of only printing the class name every time?

Comment: the result printed is <QuerySet [<Question: Question object (1)>]> and the result that I want is to replace the ```Question object (1)``` with the question that I already set

Comment: can you restart the server and delete the pyc/pycache files if those are generated?

Comment: It works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `__repr__` instead of `__str__` (or both)
From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

> Called by the repr() built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object.

Comment: the result printed is still only the class name instead of ```question_text```